# Find the value of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the sequence $a_n = 1^9 + 2^9 + ... + n^9 -an^{10}$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am given the following sequence:

$$a_n = 1^9 + 2^9 + ... + n^9 - an^{10}$$

Where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. I have to find the value of $a$ for which the sequence $a_n$ is convergent (Or conclude that there is no such value of $a$).

How can I find this value (or that there is no such value)? I don't know how to approach something like this at all.

Comment: By [Faulhaber's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaulhabersFormula.html), $1^9+2^9+...+n^9=\frac1{10}n^{10}+O(n^9)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  while that is correct, it is not useful for the problem.  $n^9$ can diverge even if we choose $a=-\frac 1{10}$

Comment: @RossMillikan: you probably mean $O(n^9)$ might converge anyway ? In fact, we have $\Theta(n^9)$.

Comment: A much better question would be to multiply the expression by $\frac 1{n^9}$  Now it converges for $a=-\frac 1{10}$ and no other.  Without the division no value of $a$ works.

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$
\begin{align}
b_n:=a_{n+1}-a_n&=(n+1)^9-a(n+1)^{10}+an^{10}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^9n^k-a\sum_{k=0}^9\binom{10}{k}n^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^9n^k\left(1-a\binom{10}{k}\right)
\end{align}
$$

If $a\neq\frac{1}{10}$, this is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $9$. So as $n\to\infty$, $\{b_n\}$ will diverge.

If $a=\frac{1}{10}$, this is $\sum_{k=0}^8n^k\left(1-\frac{1}{10}\binom{10}{k}\right)$, a polynomial in $n$ of degree $8$. So again, as $n\to\infty$, $\{b_n\}$ will diverge.

In order for the sequence $\{a_n\}$ to converge, it is necessary for the successive differences $\{b_n\}$ to converge to $0$. Therefore $\{a_n\}$ diverges no matter what $a$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$a_{n+1}=a_n+(n+1)^9+an^{10}-a(n+1)^{10}.$$

In this recurrence, the term of degree $9$ has the coefficient $1-10a$. If this coefficient is nonzero, the polynomial grows to infinity. Otherwise, the coefficient of the term of degree $8$ is $9-45a$, which is nonzero, and the polynomial grows to infinity.

Comment: @BarryCipra: quite right, thanks for the check. I am fixing.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sum_{1}^{n} k^p \sim \frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}~~~~~~(1)$$

So $a$ needs to be $\frac{1}{10}.$ for $$\frac{1^9+2^9+3^9+4^9+...n^9}{n^{10}}$$
to be convergent.

**Proof of (1)**

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^p}{n^{p+1}}= \int_{0}^{1} x^p dx=\frac{1}{p+1}$$

Further to @Ross Millikan the correct question should to what value
$$\frac{1^9+2^9+3^9+4^9+...n^9}{n^{10}}$$ will converge to. The answer is $\frac{1}{10}.$

Comment: You are right, see my edit.

Comment: Mh, you don't really answer the question about convergence of $a_n$.

Comment: The question as it is invalid and the answer is that for no value of $a$ convergence will be achieved!